# Android Studio Nexus 6 emulator going half screen. How to resize it or drag it so its fully visible

Tags: android, android-studio

I launched a Nexus 6 emulator in Android studio. But its seen as below. How do I resize it so I can see it fully.
[image]

Comment: Can't solve your problem, but you could take a look at https://www.genymotion.com/ which is a way faster and in my opinion overall better emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to resize it you can try to scale the virtual device.

In the Android Virtual Device Manager, click "Edit this AVD", then in "startup size and orietation section" choose "10dp on device = 1 px on screen" scale.

If it is too small, choose another scale... on my screen auto scale works well

You can also try to remove the skin to gain space: from "Edit this AVD":
Advanced settings -> custom skin definition -> none

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been answered, but the answer did not work for me; it was still stuck in the top. However, if you press `alt+space` and `M` for move, then use your arrow keys to scoot it down and over. Cheers